# CSS Div Styles Don't Apply To One Button

Tags: css

I have a problem. I have CSS styles for 9 buttons on my webpage but `#a` doesn't work. All the other 8 ones are working fine. (The CSS is paired with HTML and Javascript, I'm trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe Game.) (*Note: I removed some code, because its all the same.*)

```
#a {
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
    top:150px;
    <!-- The Green Text Is Purely For De-bug purposes -->
    text-color:green;
}
#b {
    position:absolute;
    left:150px;
    top:150px;
}
#c {
    position:absolute;
    left:250px;
    top:150px;
}
#d {
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
    top:200px;
}
```

Comment: Show us the HTML (or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) with the issue.

Comment: It's not relevant in this case, 99.999% of the text, is javascript. The HTML is just a bunch of divs and a form with 9 buttons, plus a turn counter, and a thing that says who's turn it is.

Comment: Does is work if you take out the `text-color` and the comment? Because, for color it is `color:green;` and comments in CSS are `/* comment */`

Comment: No, the green text was to find out if the problem was with the div, or the CSS, the green text did nothing to my "HelloWorld" I typed beside the button.

Comment: Nor would it, if you spelled it `text-color` (and don't be too quick to assume the HTML isn't relevant; you've got at least one incorrect assumption *somewhere*)

Comment: The comment syntax here is wrong, I don't know if you actually have that in your code. You should use `/* ... */` to comment your CSS lest you want the parser to break and ignore your code.

Comment: The HTML (the DOM) is absolutely relevant, even if it's generated by JS -- the `#a` rule could fail, for example, if there is more that one DOM element with `id="a"`

Comment: @StephenP is absolutely correct in both of his comments. `text-color` does not exist, and is simple `color`. And your comments styling can mess up the rest of the declaration since comments are denoted with `/* Comments */` and not the notation you have currently.

Comment: @PaulRoub The HTML is correct, because, the javascript, which uses the `document.GetElementById("a").innerHTML ="laah Blaah Blaagh";` , works fine, with the id of a.

Comment: If you do CSS comments inside a HTML document, it doesn't show them as comments, when using notepad++, however, it does recognize HTML comments, CSS comments in a CSS document, and JS comments, inside <script> tags, or a JS document. Hence, I goofed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the comments, I tried with and without them and it turns out they should be

```
/* Blaah */
```

instead of

```
<!-- Blaah -->
```